# My image rotate 90 degree

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

For some reason, my pictures after being published on the site are turned upside down by 90 degrees, and everything looks fine in the admin panel. How to fix it ?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the website?
If you can't provide a link - then can you please provide the CSS from the inspector?
It's hard to come up with a solution, if we can't see the problem. It may be a CSS problem - please look out for "transform: rotate();" in your CSS for the specific element. Further information on this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Upside down would be 180°.  If it is 90°, are all images rotated in the same direction?

Answer (score -1):

You can add jquery .css() method

```
jQuery('.image_class_name').css('transform','rotate(-90deg)');
```

change the degree as you want.